# Why does inserting a new R chunk inside `ess-noweb-mode` give me a leading @ symbol?

Tags: key-bindings, ess, r, literate-programming

I am writing a statistical report using `.Rnw` buffer and enjoying the very nice `ess-noweb-mode`, which I see very promising indeed, but what struck me is the strange behavior when I hit the keybinding to insert a new chunk <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> it will introduce an extra `@` symbol at the very beginning of the chunk, is this an expected behavior or am I missing some point here? your input would be much appreciated.

```
@ 
<<anyChunkName>>=
R code goes here
@ %def
```

I had to delete that leading `@` each time writing an R chunk to appear like this:

```
<<anyChunkName>>=
R code goes here
@ %def
```

**Note**
I am using ESS vesrion 15.09-2 patched

Comment: ESS-noweb-mode is 'semi-obsolete', and as such is not currently maintained: https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/215 . The replacement is polymode: https://github.com/vspinu/polymode . Polymode is undergoing rapid development; however, last I tried it there were still some rough edges to be addressed. Maybe now, or soon, it will be much better than what ess-noweb ever was.

Comment: thanks for the input, hoping that `polymode` would be the ultimate tool.

Answer (score 2):

In my emacs and ess, I just typed "<" then

```
<<>>=
@
```

comes out automatically.

Comment: Wecome to emacs SE! Please use comments if you want to help but don't know the answer.

Comment: a great tip! however,I cannot see it as an answer, as it didn't *specifically* answer the question.